# how to find probability If we have a sample of 2000 couples, each with three kids, the probable number of couples with two sons and one daughter is?

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have a sample of 2000 couples, each with three kids, the probable number of couples with two sons and one daughter is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a family with 3 kids, the number $X$ of sons follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n=3$ and $p=0.5$ (good approximation :-) So the probability that this family has two sons and a daughter is ${\rm P}(X=2)=\binom32\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac38$.

Now for $2000$ families, the number $Y$ of families having two sons and a daughter follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n=2000$ and $p=\frac38$. The expectation of this random variable is ${\rm E}(Y)=np=2000\times\frac38 = 750$.

Comment: I am thinking like this 

answer->500 : If we look at the possible combinations . There are 4 scenarios as mentioned below .

3 kids can be :

All boys

2 boys and 1 gal

1 boy and 2 gals

All gals

So the probability of having 2 sons and 1 daughter is 1/4 . And total number of couples with this combination are

2000 * 1/4 = 500

so answer might be 500

Comment: I am bit of confused between @nicolas solution and my solution 
so my question is when we should apply binomial distribution?

Comment: Suppose you differentiate the childs by order of arrival. Then 2 sons and a daughter can come from three different cases : SSD, SDS and DSS. You have to count those three possibilities, which adds up to a probability of $3\left(\frac12\right)^3=\frac38$. For example, there is only one case for 3 sons : SSS, which probability is $\left(\frac12\right)^3=\frac18$.

Answer (score 0):

we look at the possible combinations .
There are 4 scenarios as mentioned below . 
3 kids can be : 
All boys 
2 boys and 1 gal 
1 boy and 2 gals 
All gals 
So the probability of having 2 sons and 1 daughter is 1/4 . 
And total number of couples with this combination are 2000 * 1/4 = 500